# How do I retrieve a value from struct object by previously stored ID? C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a C++ script with a struct object 'Particle' , with x, y ,z position stored. I create several particle objects with unique ID's. How do I get the position of a particle by ID? Something like: particle.getPosByID(int ID);

My code is as follows:

```
struct Particle {
Vector position     { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
Vector velocity     { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
Vector acceleration { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
Vector color        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; // RED
int ID = 0;}
```

I've tried within the struct:

```
    float getPosX(int ID)
{
    return this->position.x;
}
```

with:`float ix = particles->getPosX(5);`

but no luck. Any ideas? Would I need a class with getters? If so, how do I go about that? Struct has been good and easy to use so far...

Thanks!

EDITED

Vector is a struct:

```
struct Vector
{
float x, y, z;}
```

Particles are stored using an array:

```
const int MaxParticles = 5;
Particle particles[MaxParticles];
```

Comment: Can you update this post so we have a snippet of code that we are able to compile ourself?

Comment: How are you storing these `Particle`s?

Comment: You'll have to show us how you create these items and how you're storing them. Read through [mcve] and work on updating your question.

Comment: How is `Vector ` implemented? Could you please add it to the problem?

Comment: Edited problem to include details on vector and particle container

Comment: You "get the position of a particle by ID" by writing the C++ code to do it. Plain and simple. There are scant few things that C++ will do it for you, by itself. You will have to devise some mechanism to keep track of all instances of this class that exist, at any given moment in time, and then search them for the instance with a particular ID. You will have to write all the code to do this. C++ will not do it for you, except provide generic containers that you can use to implement this. Since you store them in an array, write the code to search the array.

Comment: This isn't very clear and you're going to have to flesh it out a bit. Have you used arrays? Do you know how to search in an array? Have you considered a container like a map? That can map an index to an object? It sounds like that's what you need. Read the chapter in your book about containers and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

> Particles are stored using an array

If the particle IDs correspond to array indices, then access that array by id:

```
float ix = particles[id].position.x;
```

If not, you'll probably be better off storing them inside some associative structure like a `map`:

```
std::map<int, Particle> particles;
```

You can drop the id from the struct then, and use the same code as above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you store the particles in an array, you have to go through them one by one to check

```
float getPosX(int ID)
{
    for (auto const & p : particles) { // assume particles are a global variable
        if (p.ID == ID) 
            return p.position.x;
    }
    return 0; // or some value to indicate error or not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an array to store your particles and the array indices do not correspond to the particle ids, then you need to just search the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Vector { 
    float x, y, z;
};

struct Particle {
    int ID;
    Vector position     { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    Vector velocity     { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    Vector acceleration { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    Vector color        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; // RED
};

int main() {
    const int MaxParticles = 5;
    Particle particles[MaxParticles] = {{0},{3},{2},{4},{5}};

    // find particle with loop
    int findid = 3;
    for(size_t i=0;i< MaxParticles;++i)
    {
        if (particles[i].ID == findid)
        {
            std::cout << "found partcile with id " << findid <<  " at index " << i << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    // find particle with std::find_if
    auto iter = std::find_if(particles,particles+MaxParticles, [&](const Particle& p){
        if (p.ID == findid)
            return true;
        return false;
    });

    std::cout << "Found particle " << iter->ID << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/kSsMph)

You would be likely be better off to just use an associative container like std::map as suggested in one of other answers though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is class definition which can help you to achieve this. Here you can use std::map instead of array 'particles' for better search performance.

```
struct Particle 
{
    /// This is your existing particle struct
}

class Particles
{
    const int MaxParticles = 5;
    Particle particles[MaxParticles];
    Particles()
    {

    }

    void AddParticle(Particle p)
    {
        ///Insert particle 'p' into array 'particles'
    }

    void RemoveParticle(Particle p)
    {
        ///Remove particle 'p' from array 'particles'
    }

    Particle GetParticle(int ID)
    {
        Particle p;
        ///Add loop over 'particles' to search particle with specified ID and then return that particle
        return p;
    }

    Vector GetParticlePosition(int ID)
    {
        Vector v;
        ///Add loop over 'particles' to search particle with specified ID and then return it postion
        return v;
    }
}
```